# Placing JavaFX Text over an image

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently using javafx.scene.text.Text to add a stroke and change the text color but I need to place my text over an image in a specified X,Y position. Is there any way to do this with the javafx text I'm currently using? Or what else can I use to replicate what I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your ImageView in a Stackpane, and on top of the view a Group containing your Text with the according X/Y coordinates set.

Comment: If I want to save that image to .png after, what would I have to do?

Comment: Well, you could take a snapshot of the stackpane using ´Node#snapshot(...)`. This will give you a `WritableImage`, which you can convert to a BufferedImage instance using `SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(...)`, and then write that to disk via `ImageIO`.